# Regex to remove Authorization header from logging output?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, logging

I've recently realised that we're accidentally logging `Authorization` headers to our prod log drain.

An example output looks like:

```
{"response":{"status":"rejected","reason":{"message":"read ECONNRESET","name":"Error","stack":"Error: read ECONNRESET\n    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Authorization":"Token eyJra...rest...of.token","Content-Type":"application/json","User-Agent":"axios/0.27.2"},"method":"get","url":"https://api.mywebapp.com"},"code":"ECONNRESET","status":null}}}
```

This is being logged via `winston`, with a `logger.info(JSON.stringify(errorObj))`.

Winston allows for custom formatters, so all I need is a regex to strip the `"Authorization: '(Token|Bearer) key_value'` pattern from the string.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: You could remove the key on `errorObj` before stringifying it. I realise it doesn't answer the regex question but could be a solution to you problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`.replace(/Authorization\"\:\"[^\"]+/, "Authorization\":\"##token##")`

Explanation:

1. `Authorization\"\:\"`: Search for `Authorization` followed by `":"`
2. `[^\"]+` : Get everything that is not `"`, meaning until the closing `"`
3. `"Authorization\":\"##token##"` : Replace the match by hiding the token